# Exclude and filter graphene django query set

Tags: python, django, graphene-django

Hi i'm trying to add a filter and exclude to my query set but don't know how. I can filter and exclude separately but cant do it simultaneously.

**This is my resolver**

```
    def resolve_articles(self, info, limit=None, offset=None, slug=None, search=None, exclude=None, braking=None, non_braking=None):
        if search:
            filter = (
                Q(id__icontains=search) |
                Q(title__icontains=search) |
                Q(categories__name__icontains=search)
            )

            return BlogPage.objects.filter(filter).order_by('-first_published_at')[offset:limit]
```

**How can i do this**

```
    def resolve_articles(self, info, limit=None, offset=None, slug=None, search=None, exclude=None, braking=None, non_braking=None):
        if search and exclude:
            filter = (
                Q(id__icontains=search) and
                Q(categories__name__icontains=exclude)
            )

            return BlogPage.objects.filter(filter).exclude(filter).order_by('-first_published_at')[offset:limit]
```

Thank you

Comment: `and` will give you only the last `Q` object. You can use `Q(id__icontains=search, categories__name__icontains=exclude)` is filter, but it is rather *strange* that you `.filter(..)` and `.exclude(..)` on the same item?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem need to filter for posts in a specific category and exclude the current post. thats why i'm using bot `.filter(..)` and `.exclude(..)` The combining of search and exclude in Q object, as you suggested, didn't seam to work.

Comment: This is probably a year late but your second example doesn't make sense. First of all, don't use `and` between Q, it will do a logical condition between the filter expressions, you need `&` that is normally the bitwise and but is overloaded by Django to merge filters. Then, you shouldn't filter and exclude the same thing. filter on the search criteria (like in your first example) and then exclude just on a condition of the current post.